# Type Error in Python 3. Expected string or buffer but u' occured at index 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'
def preprocess(line,
           token_pattern=token_pattern,
           exclude_stoptword=config.cooccurrence_word_exclude_stopword,
           encode_digit=False):

    token_pattern=re.compile(token_pattern,re.UNICODE)
    tokens=[x.lower() for x in token_pattern.findall(line)]

    tokens_stemmed=stem_tokens(tokens,english_stemmer)
    if exclude_stoptword:
        tokens_stemmed=[x for x in tokens_stemmed if x  not in stopwords]
    return tokens_stemmed

def extract(df):
    #Unigram Features 

    df["query_unigram"]=list(df.apply(lambda x:preprocess(df["query"]),axis=1))
```

Got the following error:

```
    tokens=[x.lower() for x in token_pattern.findall(line)]
TypeError: ('expected string or buffer', u'occurred at index 0')
```

df["query"] contains:

0     bridal shower decorations

1          led christmas lights

2                     projector

3                     wine rack

4                    light bulb

5        oakley polarized radar

6               boyfriend jeans

7      screen protector samsung

8             pots and pans set

9                  waffle maker

Comment: So perhaps `line` is not a string? What does `print(repr(line))` tell you `df.apply` passes to your function instead?

Comment: Can you show us what is contained in your dataframe, specifically in `df['query']`?

Comment: And isn't `df['query']` the *whole column*? I'm not that familiar with Pandas.

Comment: Line is a series object.

Comment: So you can't apply a regex to that..

Comment: thank you Pieters. I made a mistake in this line                                                          df["query_unigram"]=list(df.apply(lambda x:preprocess(df["query"]),axis=1))                                                                              Instead of 'df' I should use x